# C++: Proper way to share value (data) between different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, lidar, atomicinteger

I have the following Thread.cpp:

```
   while (1) 
    {
       rplidar_response_measurement_node_t nodes[8192];
       size_t   count = _countof(nodes);

       op_result = drv->grabScanData(nodes, count);

       if (IS_OK(op_result)) 
        {
           drv->ascendScanData(nodes, count);

           for (int pos = 0; pos < (int)count ; ++pos) 
            {

               nodes[pos].sync_quality & RPLIDAR_RESP_MEASUREMENT_SYNCBIT;
               nodes[pos].angle_q6_checkbit >> RPLIDAR_RESP_MEASUREMENT_ANGLE_SHIFT/64.0f;
               nodes[pos].distance_q2/4.0f;
               nodes[pos].sync_quality >> RPLIDAR_RESP_MEASUREMENT_QUALITY_SHIFT;
            }
        }
    }
  return ;
}
```

Motion Thread.cpp

```
void Motion::Synchronization(QString motiontype)
{
      if(motiontype == START)
       {

   if(269<Thread::angle_q6_checkbit && Thread::angle_q6_checkbit <271)
    {
        if(Thread::distance_q2>1200)
        {
            dist_left=1200;
        }
     else
      {
           dist_left=Thread::distance_q2;
      }
                cout<<"Motion +Stuff+="<< endl;
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't my exact code, this is the part where I will get the data and storing data into the variable. `distance_q2, angle_q6_checkbit`, etc. are NOT an atomic variable, so reading and writing them from a different thread is not consistent!! In the same thread, if I tried to print data I am getting the proper reading. The output is given below.

[image: Proper data from Thread.cpp]

Now, I have tried to take the data for processing or other my stuff. Storing the distance, angle quality data like to `Thread::sync_quality, Thread::angle_q6_checkbit, Thread::distance`

Taking data from Laser data `Thread.cpp` to `motion.cpp` thread (cout data in motion thread):

```
cout << "distance "<< Thread::distance_q2 << endl;
cout << "angle "<< Thread::angle_q6_checkbit << endl;
cout << "quality level "<< int(Thread::sync_qualitylevel) << endl;
```

I am getting improper output (getting only 359 degrees, that also improper). I can't able to conclude. Now the output for the above is:

[image: Improper data with another thread motion.coo]

I've tried to declare then as atomic, but I can't see any improvement. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't with the sharing, but in your calculations? How much of the data is shared? Is it "true" sharing, where each thread access the exact same data? Or is each thread using different parts of the data (for example thread one uses array elements `0` to `9`, thread two uses array elements `10` to `19`, etc.)? Does it work if you run only a single thread? Or call the function directly without using threads at all?

Comment: And have you tried to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? It's not easy with multi-threaded programs, but if you step through *one* thread in a debugger, does it do what you expect it to do? You could also add some debug-logging or output to help figure out where the problem might be.

Comment: If the problem within my calculation, then same thread only I will not get proper data, but I am getting proper data continuously (  theta: 0.11 Dist: 00000.00 Q: 0 
   theta: 0.73 Dist: 00000.00 Q: 0  theta: 1.38 Dist: 00000.00 Q: 0 
   theta: 3.30 Dist: 00000.00 Q: 0 to    theta: 358.84 Dist: 08949.00 Q: 47 
   theta: 359.48 Dist: 08986.00 Q: 47 ). Yes, it is true and motion thread access the exact same data. Once if I am getting same data then only I can take different parts. Thread1,2,3,4,5 started and stopped properly. If I want to share data from this thread, that is not happening.

Comment: It is not happening means, I am not getting proper data.

Comment: I can't see any kind of inter thread communication here. Simply read/write on the same variables will ever fail! mutex? atomic? shared memory? pipes? What is the question about?

Comment: Storing the distance, angle, quality data to Thread::sync_quality, Thread::angle_q6_checkbit, Thread::distance. When I am try to use this data to other thread I am not getting the full data I am getting only last data theta: 359.48 Dist: 08986.00 Q: 47. mutex? atomic? shared memory? pipes? I am not sure, What can I use to get the proper data. I have updated the part of  thread communication.

Comment: I think problem because of for loop. I am getting the output data like this.                          // from Thread.cpp
theta: 357.36 Dist: 09147.00 Q: 47 
theta: 358.00 Dist: 08823.00 Q: 47 
theta: 358.64 Dist: 08964.00 Q: 47 
theta: 359.92 Dist: 09140.00 Q: 47 
distance 9140  // from motionthread.cpp
angle 359
quality level 47
distance 9140
angle 359
quality level 47
distance 9140
angle 359
quality level 47
theta: 0.12 Dist: 00000.00 Q: 0   // from Thread.cpp
theta: 0.77 Dist: 00000.00 Q: 0 
theta: 1.42 Dist: 00000.00 Q: 0 after completed for loop i am getting last data

Comment: So, if this is a problem, what can be the solutions.